# Dapper - Query multiple models

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

My query involves multiple tables and from what I've read on Dapper, I can only find examples, that I understand at least, that query one model.

Below are my 3 classes under the Models folder:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    public string LastLogin { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public class UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository I have my connection code and then a method to get all the information I need, however this method is tied to the `User` model only but I also need to retrieve the photo and when I try to make a compound class so I can the `User` and `Photo` models in the view, it gives me an error saying it expects only the `User` DataView.

```
public List<User> GetAll()
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var allResults = cn.Query<User>("SELECT UserName, Email, Phone, (SELECT TOP 1 PhotoPath FROM Photo WHERE User.UserId = Photo.UserId) FROM User)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` class does not contain property like `PhotoPath` - where you expect Dapper put will new/additional value to?

You should create new class (`ViewModels/UserAndPhoto.cs` for example), which contains all properties you are selecting - then Dapper will read it from database successfully.

Comment: I always assumed the classes corresponded to tables in the database, since User and Photo are two different tables I thought they had to be different classes. Is this not the case?

Comment: In EntityFramework - yes, in Dapper - no. It simply maps fields (in query) to properties (in class) by name - you should only care about datatype.

Comment: The fields on the class should directly reflect the columns that are returned in your select statement. Doesn't matter what the tables are, only the select statement.